# Reveal a password for the following JS code

Tags: javascript, html

I got this in a job interview and I didn't knew the answer...
I was given by an HTML file that runs a JS and I needed to find the password.

When I ran the HTML file, I got everything except a 'Good job' or 'Too bad' strings.
I found up that there's probably an hidden code that over riding this code (I think so just because I couldn't see such strings at the code I found inside this HTML file).

Anyway... I copied the code from the origin file and saved it as a new HTML, then I got the 'Too bad' instead of the hidden code's weird messages.

I'll be more than happy if someone could explain the following code to me and tell me how he revealed the correct password.

Thanks !!

**The code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function c(x){ alert((document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value == window.location.hostname.replace(/a-f/, '%')) ? 'Good job!' : 'Too bad!'); }
</script>
Password: <input /><br />
<button onclick="c()">Check</button>
```

I upload the HTML file to: http://www.filedropper.com/secretpass

Comment: Did you read this JS code? What part don't you understand?

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value == window.location.hostname.replace(/a-f/, '%')

What this condition's  meaning for the password ? how do I reveal the password ? I don't know the URL and I don't know (first of all)  the meaning of this condition...

Comment: That's an ordinary equality comparison (eg, `a === b`).  What part of it don't you understand?

Comment: I understood that the JS compare the first letter of my pass (('input')[0].value) that the only thing that matter in this pass is its first character ? to window.location.hostname.replace(/a-f/, '%') that I really don't know what it means... I don't know JS...

Comment: Just as a side thought, if the job wants you to be able to read and (presumably) write JavaScript and HTML, and you can't, are you sure this is the kind of job you want to be applying for?

Comment: It does indeed seem the interview question weeded out what it was meant to. @Batman, it's `[0].value` not `.value[0]`. It's not the first character of the value, but the value of the first element in  the `getElementsByTagName` result set.

Comment: It's a logical question, but I can't understand how can I find the host-name from the file itself ?? I understood now the compare's condition but I really need to know somehow the host-name in order to get the correct pass...

Comment: @Batman: [Look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qxa8g/). I've refactored the code so that it may be easier to read, but it's the functional equivalent of what you've posted. In this particular case, the password is `fiddle.jshell.net` as that is the host of the frame in which the result is being shown (a bit trickier with framed websites, for sure!) If you look at [the same code hosted at jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/ojudub/1/) the correct answer is `jsbin.com`.

Comment: Only now I've seen your answer.. sorry for the late response. I didn't said that the code does different things than it should as you exampled, but can you download the file from http://www.filedropper.com/showdownload.php/secretpass ? this is the actual file I received as an attachment to my Gmail... and tell me your opinion. thx !

Comment: Hah! Look at the **bottom** of the source! Here's the real code, pretty-printed by JSFiddle then pasted into JSBin with the HTML restored: http://jsbin.com/axuyuw/1/edit

Comment: [956918b1820bc657](http://jsbin.com/axuyuw/10/edit) Do I get the job? ;)

Comment: Sorry for the late response (different time areas, it was 1:00am...), How did you find this code? I scrolled down all over the original file after opening it using the notepad and found nothing but the code I originally paste..., and after carefully review this code, what should be the real password ? thx

Comment: Well, it's right there in the file you uploaded. Look for "urchin".

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value == window.location.hostname.replace(/a-f/, '%')
```

This code compares the value of the input to a string derived from the URL hostname.

It is used as the comparand to a conditional operator displaying the messages.

Comment: So what should I do in order to actually get the password itself ?

Comment: I don't know what's the meaning of document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value == window.location.hostname.replace(/a-f/, '%') 

in JS... but I understood here that I need to find the host name in order to reveal the pass. This pass is very important to me and I'm desperate to reveal it but I can't...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the password would depend on which web site was hosting this script.  The c function looks at window.location.hostname (www.google.com for example) and replaces the first occurance of either a,b,c,d,e or f with a percent sign "%".  I don't think the percent sign holds any significance in JS regex notation, so the password would be www.y%hoo.com if the script were hosted on www.yahoo.com

Comment: I can guarantee you it has a URL; it'll probably be either a file:// or http://localhost/ URL, but it will definitely have one.

Comment: So what should be the way to find it ? I think they located it in some hidden way in that file...

Comment: I think this replaces a literal string "a-f" in the URL, not a range. If it were a range, it would need to be `/[a-f]/`. So this would only do something for a hostname like `www.a-foo.com`, which would have a password of `www.%oo.com`.

Comment: @AKHolland: How can I find the URL of this HTML file ?

Comment: @Batman: as the password is derived from `location.host`, it will be a different one depending on where the file is hosted. If you just save it as an html file on your computer and open up from there, `location.host` will be an empty string and then so will the password.

Comment: I got it as an attachment file to my Gmail... means they wants me to tell them the pass is actually nothing ?...

Comment: You got it as an attachment? Jesus, they may know less about interview questions than you do about javascript. I think you might be their man! Tell them that the password is derived from the hostname which will differ depending on the environment where the code is executed, and yes, that it will be an empty string if you just download the file and run it off your computer.

Comment: But when I just click the 'Check' with an empty string, it gives me Too bad !

Anyway, I upload the file to: http://www.filedropper.com/secretpass and I'll be more that happy if you can take a look at it... thx

Answer (score 0):

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2KKZt/1/) shows the behavior of the thing. I added an additional function that simply shows the expected password. In this case, the expected password is `fiddle.jshell.net`, since that is the host for the frame where the resulting document is sitting.

So yes, the password is directly derived from the URL of the webpage. If it was simply an HTML file on your local machine, like you mentioned above, its URL is something like

```
file:///C:/Users/yourname/Desktop/jobtest.html
```

It's whatever shows in the address bar. However, I am skeptical that it was this simple, because for a webpage running at a `file://` URL, we have

```
window.location.hostname == ""
```

meaning that the password is simply the empty string. So you would leave the input field blank and click the button. maybe if you ran it on a local server it would work, in which case the password would be `localhost`, as @Chris mentioned.

But I also suspect you may have copied the code slightly wrong. Maybe not, maybe it was just a trick to slip you up, but the regular expression in the `replace()` function seems wrong. Instead of

```
`window.location.hostname.replace(/a-f/, '%')`
```

I would expect

```
`window.location.hostname.replace(/[a-f]/, '%')`
```

which would replace the first lowercase `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, or `f` with a `%`. So instead of `localhost`, you would have `lo%alhost`.

Anyway, as it stands from your question, the password is simply the hostname portion of the URL, with the first instance of `a-f` replaced by a `%`. So instead of `www.zelda-forever.com`, you would have `www.zeld%orever.com`.

Comment: Oh, does replace only do the first instance? Haven't used it in a while.

Comment: Yes, unless you specify that the expression is global, `/[a-f]/g`

Comment: Gotcha. `sed`-style regexes. Correcting the answer.

Comment: I got the file to my Gmail.. I upload it to: http://www.filedropper.com/secretpass if you want to take a look at... but the results will not be 'Too bad' or 'Good job' it will be some strange results... therefor I tried to take this file and copy its source code to another file I've created, and all I get is the ' Too bad'